# Добавить/убрать атрибут при изменении ширины

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите составить условие для html кода:

```
<div id="accordion_element" class="uk-switcher uk-accordion" data-uk-accordion></div>
```

Мне нужно убрать атрибут **data-uk-accordion** из тега , в реальном времени.

Если ширина окна браузера меньше 980px, то атрибут **data-uk-accordion** удалить из тега  и наоборот.

Comment: Что-то я сильно сомневаюсь, что удаление атрибута тебе поможет...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elem = $('#accordion_element');
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ( $(window).width() > 980 && !elem.attr('data-uk-accordion') ) {
        elem.attr('data-uk-accordion', '');
    } else {
        elem.removeAttr('data-uk-accordion');
    }
})
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Все работает.